Chosen jQuery plugin not changing HTML select
I'm trying to change the select tag from HTML to the ones used in the example on the
Chosen v1.8.7, but even after following the steps the select continues as the default one:
test.html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <select name="selecao" id="selecione" class="select">
        <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
        <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".select").chosen();
        });
    </script>
</body>

Expected result: the HTML select changed to the one found in the Chosen v1.8.7
Actual result: select tag not changed

Where do you import jquery itself? you use chosen.jquery and chosen.jquery.min, which should both be the same (you only need one of these) .?

Also, you haven't needed to have the type="test/javascript" attribute on <script> elements since.... HTML 3? Whenever we got rid of VBScript as a possibility...

importing both jquery and jquery.min isn't the issue, with one import or the other doesn't work either way.
Also I'm pretty sure that I already tried removing the 'type="text/javascript"' and it doesn't change anything so even tho it's not necessary it isn't what's causing the issue

You've included both chosen.jquery.js and chosen.jquery.min.js. Typically, these are the same script (one is just the minified version of the other).
Here's how you should modify your test.html to include all necessary scripts and styles correctly:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Chosen Plugin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="selecao" id="selecione" class="select">
        <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
        <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".select").chosen();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Check the browser console (F12 -> Console tab) for any JavaScript errors that might indicate what's going wrong.

That's not the issue, firstly I imported only the chosen.jquery,js,(and it also didn't work) and both imports shouldn't really affect each other anyways, I'll check the console later to see what can be happening

After checking the browser console the following message appears
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
jQuery 2


chosen.jquery.js:622:3
it appears twice, one for chosen.jquery.js and the js.min (already removed one of them and it still doesn't resolve it so that's definetly not the issue)
